# reading xmls with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to read this xml to get values like "Simpson" for example,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <Data Name="LastName">Simpson</Data>
        <Data Name="IdPeople">4355</Data>
        <Data Name="State" />
        <Data Name="City" />
        <Data Name="Requests">12</Data>
    </Header>
    <Body />
 </Example>
```

I do this frequently and want to use efficient code, maybe xpath is the best approach?? Some samples??

Comment: In order to recommend good tools, we'd need to know your environment. Is this a C# program? Something on Linux? Is it running in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

To get the last name, the xpath would be something like this:

```
/Example/Header/Data[Name='LastName']
```

To get the number of Requests:

```
/Example/Header/Data[Name='Requests']
```

Comment: @Ed, the `Data[Name='Requests']` element is still a child of `<Header>`, despite the indentation.

Comment: @LarsH, He changed the XML.  the original XML fit my original XPath.

Comment: `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(file.xml);
XmlNodeList node = doc.SelectNodes("/Example/Header");
foreach (XmlNode n in node)
{
    pd.FileName = n["Data[@Name='Requests']"].InnerText;
}`

Comment: sorry i was trying that code but I can indent, so sorry... and pd.FileName should get requests, what is bad??

Comment: @blur, please edit your question to put the code sample into it. Then you can format it nicely. And you can tell us what pd.FileName is getting, so we can tell you *why* it's happening.